# Keep excel table formatting after refreshing the table

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code that refreshes an Excel table using a sproc

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").OLEDBConnection
Values = QueryStr 
.CommandText = Values
End With
```

Once the refresh has completed I need to apply some formatting (trhough VBA code), the problem with this is that the code executes without waiting for the refresh to end, therefore the  VBA macro fails, is there a way I could tell the macro to wait until the refresh has completed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the BackgroundQuery property to False.

Code:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").OLEDBConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False '- Change here
    Values = QueryStr
    .CommandText = Values
End With
```

If i'm not mistaken.. this'll prevent the updates from running in the background, so it'll have to complete before the rest of your code executes.